# Real Analysis: proof limit with sigma-N definition of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Given a sequence Sn = $ \frac {1}{n^2+n}$ we have to prove the sequence converges to zero using the $\epsilon$-n definition of convergence. What I had in mind is that since  |$ \frac {1}{n^2+n}$-0|<$\epsilon$ then $ \frac {1}{n^2+n}$<0 as n is a natural number, then there must exist a N that is ≤ n, and thus > 1/$\epsilon$. Thus I can prove the sequence Sn converges to 0. But this proof seem too simple to me, and I keep thinking I'm missing steps, as N never gets used.

Comment: To prove the limit exists and converges to $0$ you must show that for any $\epsilon$ there exists an $N,$ such that $n> N \implies |\frac{1}{n^2 + n}| < \epsilon$  then you say if $N> \frac {1}{\epsilon}$  then  $|\frac{1}{n^2 + n}| < \epsilon$  Have you shown than there is an $N$ for every $\epsilon$?  Looks like it to me.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that for $n\geq 1$ we have $$\frac{1}{n^2+n}<\frac{1}{n}$$ So it is $$n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

Comment: what is the point of having a $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: heck $\frac {1}{n^2 + n} < \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: It is better to solvable for $n$

Comment: $\frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon$ if $n>\sqrt{\epsilon}$

Comment: so now my train of thought would be to use the fact that 1/n<ϵ to solve for n in relation to ϵ ?